# How can I pass a bunch of form in only one curl

Tags: php, curl, post, foreach

So what im doing is:

```
        foreach ($textAr as $title) {
        $title = str_replace("\r", '', $title);
        echo nl2br($title . "\n");

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://a...',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
  "title":"' . $title . '",
  "category_id":"' . $categorytxt . '",
  "price":' . $pricetxt . ',...

        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $_SESSION['access_token'] . ''
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    echo $response;
}
```

So for each title I put into a textarea it is going to do this curl request, but the problem is sometimes I have like 3000 title, so if i just foreach it cut my connection. Do u guys know another way so I can pass all curls just once, instead of one by one ?

Comment: You need to find out first that the URL where you are sending curl request can accept multiple titles in a single request or not? (in form of array of titles or json of titles). If they provide this facility then you can use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to do in one call.(by adding all data into one variable and pass it in one go)

Comment: Add all the data into an array then converting it to json and sending it at once

Comment: @ServingQuarantineperiod Sadly its not possible;

Comment: @Lftbrito  sadly then you are helpless too. In case you can run this in background then try to use cronjob for it

Comment: If you can’t do anything about the sheer number of HTTP requests you need to make, then perhaps try and see if changing how you are making & processing them on your end brings any improvement – https://www.php.net/curl_multi_init, https://thisinterestsme.com/php-non-blocking-curl/